# How to setup slideout.js? Does not work

Tags: javascript, menu, slide

I can't setup slideout.js
I do everything according to instructions: https://github.com/Mango/slideout#full-example but does not work.
Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/weranda/ma4pvg5p/)

```
enter code here
```

Can you help with it?
What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The demo was insufficient in this case.

You also need to attach an event listener to the button to trigger the slideout effect.

Here's a quick demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/therouxdown/ma4pvg5p/3/

```
document.querySelector('#panel button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  slideout.toggle();
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, but i chose a different plugin.

Comment: The example doesn't quite work because the #menu doesn't animate over like the button does.  
When opening the menu, what I see is the panel immediately appear as the button animates over.  Closing has the panel stay open while the button animates back over it and then the panel closes.

Comment: All I did was add the event listener. I didn't change any CSS-- that's all coming straight from the plugin demo example. The plugin/documentation also may have been updated since I submitted the original answer.